# Overflow doesn't work properly with pure CSS cubes

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make a background with pure CSS (Using CSS triangles with the help of border property) and I was successful so far. But there's an overflow issue that's destroying whole thing.

[image]

as shown in above image; I want 3rd cube exactly on the right side of 2nd cube (half hidden).

CSS:

```
.cube {
        float: left;
        height:239px;
        width:200px;
    }

        .cube .top {
        }

         .cube .top .high{
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-bottom: 60px solid #46B535;
                border-left: 100px solid transparent;
                border-right: 100px solid transparent;
            }
            .cube .top .low {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-top: 60px solid #46B535;
                border-left: 100px solid transparent;
                border-right: 100px solid transparent;
            }

        .cube .left {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            top: -60.7px;
        }

            .cube .left .high {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-bottom: 60px solid #59BE32;
                border-right: 100px solid transparent;
            }

            .cube .left .mid {
                height: 60px;
                width: 100px;
                background: #59BE32;
            }

            .cube .left .low {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-top: 60px solid #59BE32;
                border-left: 100px solid transparent;
            }

        .cube .right {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            top: -60.7px;
        }


            .cube .right .light .up {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-bottom: 60px solid #27B138;
                border-left: 100px solid transparent;
            }

            .cube .right .light .down {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-top: 60px solid #27B138;
                border-left: 100px solid transparent;
            }

            .cube .right .dark {
                position: relative;
                top: -61px;
            }

                .cube .right .dark .up {
                    width: 0;
                    height: 0;
                    border-bottom: 60px solid #00AA3A;
                    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
                }

                .cube .right .dark .down {
                    width: 0;
                    height: 0;
                    border-top: 60px solid #00AA3A;
                    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
                }

    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }

    .even {
        clear: both;
        overflow:hidden;
        height:36%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
      <section class="even">
        <section class="cube">

            <div class="top">
                <div class="high"></div>
                <div class="low"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <div class="high"></div>
                <div class="mid"></div>
                <div class="low"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="light">
                    <div class="up"></div>
                    <div class="down"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="dark">
                    <div class="up"></div>
                    <div class="down"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="cube">

            <div class="top">
                <div class="high"></div>
                <div class="low"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <div class="high"></div>
                <div class="mid"></div>
                <div class="low"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="light">
                    <div class="up"></div>
                    <div class="down"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="dark">
                    <div class="up"></div>
                    <div class="down"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="cube">

            <div class="top">
                <div class="high"></div>
                <div class="low"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <div class="high"></div>
                <div class="mid"></div>
                <div class="low"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="light">
                    <div class="up"></div>
                    <div class="down"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="dark">
                    <div class="up"></div>
                    <div class="down"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    </section>
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dGLMk/

Comment: the fiddle is working for me. I mean the 3 cubes are shown in one row. It is a width issue. Since you are using float: left, if the container width is not enough, then the elements go to the next row.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the jsfiddle. The problem is you need to give the containing element a minimum width of 3 of your cubes. When I resize the fiddle pane with the HTML such that the width is less than 3 of the cubes wide, the third one drops down to the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Eliminate the Float

Using `display: inline-block` instead of `float` with a `white-space: nowrap` on the wrapping element along with some number tweaking gives you a solid line that does not move and allows for an `overflow` of the elements. [**Here is an example fiddle** that may still need some slight adjustment on the `top` and `left` numbers, but gets close.](http://jsfiddle.net/dGLMk/6/)

Comment: I like your solution, I think that is very solid.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. `white-space: nowrap` is clever solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a container div with `overflow:hidden` and the width you need, AND re-use the section even with width enought for the 3 cubes it should work.

Check [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7HhsX/)

```
.even {
    width:700px;
}
.container {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:500px;
}
```

(and div .container is around the code you posted)

- maybe a min-width could be also an option.

Answer (score 1):

Apply this CSS to the rightmost cube that keeps wrapping down:

```
margin-right: -200px;
```

Here's a JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/dGLMk/2/. Note, this only solves it if it's the very rightmost one that's overflowing. If you need a solution to an arbitrary number of cubes overflowing, you'll need to set the `.cube` sections inside a container with `overflow: hidden;`, as Sergio suggests.